# paramRow tcl html rparam

Tags: tcl

Hi i am trying to assign tr tag using the following lib

```
proc ::html::paramRow {list {rparam {}} {cparam {}}} {
    ::set html "<tr $rparam>\n"
    ::foreach x $list {
        append html \t[cell $cparam $x td]\n
    }
    append html "</tr>\n"
    return $html
}
```

Here is the actual invocation

```
puts $infile [html::paramRow [list $TestCaseName $IDFNumber $Actual_Output $Expected_Output $RESULT2 {rparam {fail}}]]
```

The `< tr >` tag is not getting assigned but and i am getting following
output

```
<tr >
<td>Data1</td>
<td>Data2</td>
<td>Data3</td>
<td>Data4</td>
<td>Data5</td>
<td>rparam {pass}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm betting that you were saying `{rparam {pass}}` when you got that output…

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should pass that value as a separate argument, not inside the `[list …]`:

```
puts $infile [html::paramRow [list \
        $TestCaseName $IDFNumber $Actual_Output $Expected_Output $RESULT2] \
    "fail"]
```

This is because Tcl's procedures take optional arguments positionally. (Key/value handling is done differently.)